# IBM MobileFirst Platform GSK_ERROR_BAD_KEYFILE_PASSWORD

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, ibmhttpserver

I'm catching the error **gsk error 408 (GSK_ERROR_BAD_KEYFILE_PASSWORD)** from the IHS plugins logs. IBM is recommending me the next steps to fix it:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21177702

What are the .kdb and .sth files function? If I want to generete the .sth file again, Do I need to keep the application servers (liberty) running? Where can I find more information about these files related to the IBM platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *.kdb is a collection of SSL certificates and keys. It's password-protected. The *.sth is where the obfuscated password is stored.

You can recate the *.sth with the command line tools provided by IHS and the WAS plugin.  See $IHSROOT/bin/gskcapicmd -keydb -stashpw.

The *.sth file has no real relationship the application server or any JVM. It's read by the WebServer Plugin at startup.